# Regex to replace similar delimiters of strings

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

I have checked out various Regex answers here on StackOverflow but I can't find anything related to my problem.

I have some webpage text (LaTeX actually) of forms `$inline_latex$` and `$$paragraph_latex$$` and I want to replace them respectively, using PHP with

`<span class="latex">\color{red}inline_latex</span>`

and

`<p class="latex">\color{red}paragraph_latex</p>`

i.e. replace the delimiters for $ with span tag, and for $$ with paragraph tag. Multiple strings will be replaced at once, wherever `$` and `$$` exist.

**What I have tried:** I was having a hard time with regex so I used `str_replace` three times. First one replaces `$$` with `~`, second one replaces `$` with `span`, third one replaces `~` with `p` tag. This is shoddy but it still doesn't work because I don't have a solution for the close tags. I know using regex / preg_replace is better.

Please help? **This is not homework**. I am a math instructor designing a simple class exercise webpage, and I am learning PHP. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First replace

```
\$\$([^$]+)\$\$
```

with

```
<p class="latex">\\color{red}\1</p>
```

Then replace

```
\$([^$]+)\$
```

with

```
<span class="latex">\\color{red}\1</span>
```

See demos [1](https://regex101.com/r/YqJRb2/1) and [2](https://regex101.com/r/dH1omo/1)

Comment: Thanks! I am trying this now!!